# AWS WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have been going through every thread on here and have tried all the ways I can think of. I am following the AWS deploy django tutorial and keep getting this error

ERROR   Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.

I have used eb config to edit the file to the same path thats in django.config which is endjango/wsgi but nothing I have tried has worked. Also tried wrapping it in quotes and that did not work either.

Heres my file 
django.config

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
```

Config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
  environment: django-env
  group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: django-tutorial
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: python-3.6
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue ebextensions and requirements.txt need to be in root folder. Next run eb config and edit wsgi path to match endjango/wsgi.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your wsgi path from UI. Go to configure tab and edit it there. Another option is using terminal.